# Error in pie3D (plotrix) in r

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

Lets make some data:

```
dat <- data.frame(art=c("Ål", "Gedde", "Brosme"), sum=c(708,3797,1385))
```

And when i plot this in a 3D plot, like this:

```
library(plotrix)
pie3D(dat$sum,labels=dat$art,explode=0.1, main="Arter")
```

This happens:
[image: pie3D plot]

How can I avoid that red are below green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to read the help:

> Due to the somewhat primitive method used to draw sectors, a sector that extends beyond both pi/2 and 3*pi/2 radians in either direction may not display properly. Setting start to pi/2 will often fix this, but the user may have to adjust start and the order of sectors in extreme cases

pie3D(dat$sum,labels=dat$art,explode=0.03, start=pi/2, main="Arter")

[image]

(also, the explode=0.03 looks nicer imho)